# how to block login in laravel sessionguard based on DB value?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Here is my Model for User & session guard:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'type', 'course_id', 'address', 'phone', 'status', 'avatar'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];


    public  function getUserLocked() {

         $result=DB::table('users')->where('status', 'locked')->get();


        return $result;
    }
}

public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
{

     $u=new User();
    $result= $u->getUserLocked(); 

         foreach ($result as $locked) {
               if ($locked->id== "locked");

                         return;
        }



    $this->updateSession($user->getAuthIdentifier());

    // If the user should be permanently "remembered" by the application we will
    // queue a permanent cookie that contains the encrypted copy of the user
    // identifier. We will then decrypt this later to retrieve the users.


    if ($remember) {
        $this->createRememberTokenIfDoesntExist($user);

        $this->queueRecallerCookie($user);
    }

    // If we have an event dispatcher instance set we will fire an event so that
    // any listeners will hook into the authentication events and run actions
    // based on the login and logout events fired from the guard instances.
    $this->fireLoginEvent($user, $remember);

    $this->setUser($user);
}
```

What I want is whenever the value is locked the login will fail. But I am having all log in failed unless I comment out the code which checks for locked. Where am I doing wrong exactly. I tried with static function also in User model.

Answer (score 0):

my sugesstion:

```
// you don't need this function
public  function getUserLocked() {
    $result=DB::table('users')->where('status', 'locked')->first();
    return $result;
}
```

and then:

```
public function login(AuthenticatableContract $user, $remember = false)
{
    // you can use this because you allready in user 
    if ($this->status == "locked")
          return response()->json(['message' => 'You are locked'], 403);
 ....
```

hope this help

Comment: in SessionGuard.php line 427
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined variable: locked', 'C:\wamp64\www\laravel\dev.oasis-portal.my\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php', '427', array('user' => object(User), 'remember' => false, 'u' => object(User), 'result' => object(stdClass))) in SessionGuard.php line 427

Comment: you may have dubble $$ somewhere - just guessing

Comment: can you tell me how to search $result ?

Comment: search $result what this mean?

Comment: $result=DB::table('users')->where('status', 'locked')->first(); I want to search $result..I want to know what $result has

Comment: $user is not the database object...$user is of type Authenticate so there is no status there